# Can a Mac app run AppleScript on button click?

Tags: applescript

For example, you are working in the app, you click a button which kicks off an Applescript.

Is that possible?

I read this article, which made is seem very difficult if not impossible in Mojave.

https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2018/11/17/executing-applescript-in-mac-app-on-macos-mojave/

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. But the details vary a lot. For example, what is the JavaScript supposed to do? Should it generate any user-visible output (if so, what kind)? Are you willing to use third-party code?

Comment: Also, your title talks of JavaScript, the body of AppleScript. Those are two entirely different beasts.

Comment: @DarkDust I was asking a few questions and definitely crossed the wires on this one. I meant AppleScript.

Comment: Depending on what you are wanting to do an AppleScript may not even be necessary, but you will need to deal with privacy settings using anything that wants to control another app or get anywhere near personally identifiable information.

Comment: @red_menace I want to set the desktop image. Is there API docs for the personal info? I haven't been able to find much. Thanks!

Comment: For the desktop image, take a look at NSWorkspace’s [setDesktopImageURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527228-setdesktopimageurl).